# WP HTTP Error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to downloads.wordpress.org port 80: Connection timed out

Tags: wordpress

I want upgrade wordpress but I have an error: WP HTTP Error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to downloads.wordpress.org port 80: Connection timed out

I view in server that I haven´t the ip blocked and I executed curl via ssh and not respond wordpress but when I executed curl to other domain respond.

I think wordpress blocked my ip, how I can solve this?

Thanks!